How can I override the default behavior of `list(MyEnum)`?
I have a custom enum, MyEnum, with some elements that have different names but the same value.
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 1  # Same value as A


Consequently, list(MyEnum) returns only the names of some of the members (the first name for each value):
>>>list(MyEnum)
[<MyEnum.A: 1>, <MyEnum.B: 2>, <MyEnum.C: 3>]

Apparently, list(MyEnum.__members__) returns all the names:
>>>list(MyEnum.__members__)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

However, if I try to override the __iter__() method for my enum, the override seems to fail:
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 1  # Same value as A

    @classmethod # an attempt to override list(MyEnum) that doesn't change anything  
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(list(cls.__members__)) 

Apparently list(MyEnum) doesn't ever hit the custom __iter__() (as indicated by, say, adding a print() before returning in our custom __iter__()).
Why is that?
How can I override the default behavior of list(MyEnum) so that I get all the distinct names?

You need to override __iter__ in a subclass of Enum, then use that subclass to define MyEnum. There are similarities between an instance method of a metaclass and a class method of an instance of the metaclass, but they are not the same.

Sorry, subclass of EnumType, then use that as the metaclass for MyEnum. (Enum itself is a simple instance of EnumType suitable for defining enumerated types.)

Also, __iter__ has to return an iterator, not just an iterable. It can return iter(list(cls.__members__)), but not list(cls.__members__). (That is, __iter__ has to return something with a __next__ method; list.__next__ is not defined.)

@chepner: With that many comments, you may as well write an answer...  ;-)

"Apparently list(MyEnum) doesn't ever hit the custom __iter__() " because you haven't changed the __iter__ on the type of MyEnum, you would have to do it on the metaclass

I shied away from an answer because I'm not sure what a correct implementation of __iter__ would be. (I don't know what the further implications of replacing the use of _member_map with __members__ would be.) But I suppose with that caveat, an answer could be appropriate.

@chepner yeah, there seems to be no universal right answer as to what the override should return. The question is how to implement an override in principle. Your suggestion worked, thanks.

A class method is not the same as an instance method on a metaclass, which is what __iter__ for Enum is. You need to define a new metaclass, which you can use to define a new subclass of Enum that does what you are looking for.
A caveat: I make no claim that replacing the current behavior of EnumType.__iter__ with your suggestion will be compatible with Enum's current semantics, only that this will make your definition available.
from enum import EnumType, Enum

class MyEnumType(EnumType):
    def __iter__(self):
        # Must return an Iterator, something with a __next__ method,
        # not an Iterable.
        return iter(list(self.__members__))

class MyEnumBase(Enum, metaclass=MyEnumType):
    pass

class MyEnum(MyEnumBase):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 1

assert list(MyEnum) == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']


can't this just be return iter(self.__members__)?

Probably; __members__ itself is a mappingproxy object, which is iterable.
